# Executing Selenium Grid test suite against a different URL on each node

Tags: selenium, testing, grid, webdriver

I'm looking for a way on the Selenium Grid to execute the same test suite on each node, but having each node point to a different URL.  For example, TestSuite1 will run against www.mysite1.com on Node 1 and at the same time TestSuite1 will also run against www.mysite2.com on Node 2.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Anybody got any ideas on this?